# Как настроить бота Телеграм для пересылки соообщений?

Tags: telegram-bot

Мне необходимо сделать такую штуку. Человек пишет сообщение боту, бот пересылает это сообщение на мой сайт. При этом мне должны попасть идентификатор пользователя и его сообщение которые я храню у себя в базе. Я с сайта отвечаю пользователю, отправляя сообщение боту, а он уже пересылает это сообщение пользователю. Как такое организовать?
P.S. Бота я уже создал через BotFather

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с telegram bot api внимательнее. Это делается в три строчки кода на любом языке, на котором можно послать post/get запрос и обработать ответ. Кстати, на каком языке программирования вам нужна помощь вы не написали.